# python don't write file if executed from cron job

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, cron

I wrote a python script which is fetching some data from the google analytics API, and then writes those values to a JSON-File in the webroot folder. My script is running fine and writes the JSON-File when I execute it directly or via ./analytics.py. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

I made it executable via:

```
chmod +x analytics.py
```

and added the shebang at the beginning of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

My crontab -e entry looks like this:

```
45 17 * * * /root/dashboard_scripts/analytics.py
```

The Output of **tail -f /var/log/syslog** is as follows:

```
Apr 17 15:44:01 gs-kpi cron[62390]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Apr 17 15:45:01 gs-kpi CRON[63978]: (root) CMD (/root/dashboard_scripts/analytics.py)
```

I also checked with a sample cron, if the cron is running under the user root.

My python script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import json
import re
import os
import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

save_path = '/var/www/html/'
filename = 'googleanalytics_data.json'

data = []
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '543671d681ee.p12'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'data-gserviceaccount.com'
VIEW_ID = '10'

def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes an analyticsreporting service object.
  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE_LOCATION, scopes=SCOPES)
  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
  return analytics

def get_report(analytics):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
          'reportRequests': [
              {
                  'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                  'dateRanges': [
                      {'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'yesterday'},
                      {'startDate': '14daysAgo', 'endDate': '8daysAgo'},
                      ],
                  'metrics': [
                      {'expression': 'ga:pageviews'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:pageviewsPerSession'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:users'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:goal7Starts'},
                      {'expression': 'ga:avgPageLoadTime'}
                  ],
                  "orderBys": [
                      {"fieldName": "ga:pageviews", "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"}
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ).execute()
def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
    rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    for row in rows:
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])
      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        data.append ( header + ': ' + dimension )
      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        data.append ('Date range (' + str(i) + ')' )
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          data.append ( metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value )
def main():
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)
  keys = []
  values = []
  counter = 0
  for item in data:
      try:
        key = re.search(r'ga:(.*?):', item).group()
        value = re.search(r'\d{4,5}', item).group()
        counter +=1
        if counter > 7:
            keys.append(key + '_7days')
        else:
            keys.append(key + '_14days')
        values.append(value)
      except:
          pass

  ga_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
#   print(ga_dict)

  with open(os.path.join(save_path, filename), mode='w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(ga_dict, indent=2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: it may run as different user (not root), with different privilages (may not have access to folder), with different environment (variables)

Comment: If this doesn't run as `root`, it probably doesn't have write access to `/var/www/html`. You should get error output in your mailbox.

Comment: Extend your `crontab -e entry` with `...analytics.py 2>&1 >>/tmp/analytics.log`. Read the log output if any.

Comment: I doesn't write anything to the log, as I said the cron is also running under root, checkt it with whoami to logfile.

Comment: Note that cron jobs do not automatically get the same environment your interactive shell sets up. For example, your shell has probably executed */etc/profile*, *~/.profile*, *~/.bashrc*, etc. If any of those scripts define environment variables or do other initialization (e.g., changing ulimit settings) required by your python program then that program may not behave correctly when run via cron.

Comment: What I would do to debug this is create a short shell script that runs your python program via `strace` to get an idea why it is terminating without performing the expected work. Then have cron run that script rather than the python program directly.